# How to tell dual boot menu to not show and boot to default OS until a specific key is pressed

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, dualboot

I'm trying to dual boot Windows 10 and Windows 7. I want the dual boot menu to not show and just boot to the default OS (W10) until "D" is pressed. Unfortunately, I could not find any solutions because most of those people are dual booting 10 and Ubuntu. Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think windows boot manager has that feature.All you can do is hide,unhide and change orders . To change these settings

```
Press the Windows logo key  + R.

Type msconfig in the Open box and then select OK.

Select the Boot tab.
```

You can try [other bootloaders](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Category:Boot_loaders) - like Grub, [refind](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)

The feature you are talking about is present in grub.

[how-to-hide-grub-unless-key-is-pressed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785757/how-to-hide-grub-unless-key-is-pressed)

And a note : **you can use grub without linux as well !!**

[using-grub-without-linux-for-windows-7-10-dual-boot-configuration-45pf](http://using-grub-without-linux-for-windows-7-10-dual-boot-configuration-45pf)

If above linked instructions unclear

[how-to-install-grub-from-inside-windows](https://superuser.com/questions/381285/how-to-install-grub-from-inside-windows-7)

And if want Grub look awesome then - [how-can-i-get-some-nice-eye-candy-themes-for-grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66183/how-can-i-get-some-nice-eye-candy-themes-for-grub)