# Dual boot to one OS by default, and to other OS upon keypress

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, arch-linux, bootloader

I am planning to UEFI dual boot Windows 10 and Arch Linux, currently I have one machine booting with the Windows boot manager and another to Arch through EFISTUB. On the new machine I would prefer to keep EFISTUB and then either boot to Windows 10 on a keypress or open the boot menu which would default to Windows 10 after a few seconds (this is somewhat similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1600879/how-to-tell-dual-boot-menu-to-not-show-and-boot-to-default-os-until-a-specific-k) only with Windows and Linux instead of Windows and Windows, and that the default OS upon keypress is different to with no keypress).

However, if this exact setup is not possible I would also like to know if it a similar "press key during boot to open other OS" is possible through another bootloader or even with Windows as the default boot and Arch as the boot upon keypress or boot menu access. I am also happy to abandon UEFI if it is necessary.

Comment: This question has been answered in the Unix subforum [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245411/how-to-bypass-refind-boot-loader-and-boot-straight-to-linux-os-straight). It is possible to use rEFInd to launch an OS by default by skippin the bootloader, and select a different OS on boot by holding a user-specified hotkey (e.g. W for Windows).

Comment: You can self answer here using the linked answer as a reference. Make sure you provide attribution and proper quoting.

Comment: Thanks a million. I'll answer this evening when I get it working and fully understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rEFInd` allows you to accomplish this, as answered on the [Unix subforum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245411/how-to-bypass-refind-boot-loader-and-boot-straight-to-linux-os-straight). If you have it installed as your default boot manager then you can edit `/boot/EFI/BOOT/refind.conf` to include the line `timeout -1` [which will tell `rEFInd`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html#table1) to immediately boot into the default selection and not display the boot menu, and [holding `W` during the boot sequence](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/using.html#keyboard) will boot the first Windows installation available.

By default, the "default selection" looks for the OS last booted into. To set it to Arch or any other Linux distribution, [you must set the first argument of `default_selection`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html#table1) to a either a substring of the boot description for the OS which can be found in it's `menuentry`, or a number from 1-9 specifying the boot entry in your defined boot entry.

> `default_selection "alpha,beta"` will launch `alpha` if it's available, and `beta` if `alpha` is not available but `beta` is.
>
> - Any string, which is matched against boot descriptions. Note that rEFInd matches substrings, so you don't need to specify the complete description string, just a unique substring. Thus, default_selection vmlinuz matches vmlinuz, boot\vmlinuz-5.3.0-22-generic, or any other string that includes vmlinuz. rEFInd stops searching when it finds the first match. Because rEFInd sorts entries within a directory in descending order by file modification time, if you specify a directory (or volume name, for loaders in a partition's root directory) as the default_selection, the newest loader in that directory will be the default. As a special case, one-character strings are matched against the first character of the description, except for digits.
> - A digit (1 to 9), in which case the boot loader at that position in the boot list is launched. For instance, default_selection 2 makes the second boot entry the default.

In the case of Arch, `vmlinuz` will be a specific enough string for `default_selection` if Windows is the only other OS on the system.

Keyboard shortcuts for each OS are usually the first letter of the OS but [some others are pre-defined](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/using.html#keyboard).

And if you're stuck with anything else to do with `rEFInd`, the documentation is comprehensive and provides lots of examples, [found here](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind).