# How to directly install Fedora 33 to HDD without using USB flash drive on Windows 10 machine?

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, fedora

After the previous motherboard had been "retired", my computer is upgraded. My computer is now Intel Core i5-4430 on BIOSTAR Group H81MHV3 (I know they are old), with 12GB RAM (8GB + 4GB DDR3).

I now have three internal HDD's, all Seagate. One 500 GB that is the original one; One 2TB with 10319 reallocated sectors, I know what you are thinking, but the disk has 5103 spare sectors, emulated sector size is 512 bytes while physical sector size is 4096 bytes, so only 0.25276797961983147168332353517539 spare sectors have been used, and the bad sectors have not increased in number in umpteen days. The other is newly bought 1TB one, without bad sectors.

I have downloaded Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-33-1.2.iso, I have used PowerShell to check its hash and confirmed it is good. I am using Windows 10 20H2, I have a 16 GB micro SD card which is really slow, plugged into a card reader, I use it specifically as the Windows Preinstallation Environment rescue media and I don't intent to burn the livecd to it.

I am able to use `diskpart` and DiskGenius, I can clean install Windows without problems by using just `diskpart`, `dism` and `bcdboot`, but the methods I use won't allow me to install Linux distributions to my HDD. Is there any way I can directly install Fedora 33 to my hard drive and make it bootable without using liveUSB in a Windows environment?

---

### ***Update***

OK, I know I can achieve this by simply formatting the USB drive, burn the liveCD to it, boot into the liveUSB, install to hard drive, EasyBCD and finally remake the WinPE, but these things are stupid, why should I take all the extra steps when I can repartition disks and have empty HDD's available right now?

Comment: Why not [install fedora to WSL](https://dev.to/bowmanjd/install-fedora-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-4b26)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your drives are empty then you can just treat them it as pen drive and use [rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to create Linux installer

---

Things you can try :

1. create an additional partition, or use an additional hard drive to write the liveCD image to, using [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/). Then you boot from this partition and continue the same way you would as if you'd be booting from a USB or CD.
2. {**Recommended**} install Fedora in Virtual machine like [vmware workstation](https://www.vmware.com/in/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html) using live iso , then mount your hard drive or hard drive partition in the vm and choose that disk when installer asks for the target partition
3. Replace win bootloader with Grub then use grub to boot the iso directly

> Basically :
>
> 3a. [First install grub from win](https://superuser.com/questions/381285/how-to-install-grub-from-inside-windows-7)
>
> 3b.[Edit the grub config to make it boot the iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot#:%7E:text=Once%20the%20menuentry%20has%20been,and%20press%20ENTER%20or%20F10.)

Some tools like [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and [aioboot](https://www.aioboot.com/en/) also exists  which can make the complete process a lot easy

> aioboot
>
> [Make a GRUB2 bootable CD-ROM](https://www.aioboot.com/en/aio-boot-dvd/)

Comment: The virtual machine method looks promising...

Comment: I have created a Fedora 33 virtual machine using VirtualBox, I can continue from here.